# Recipient verification for Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013

I  am attempting to do recipient verification for Exchange 2013 and not getting very far.

Everything seems to be enabled, but it's not working as expected (test is to telnet to port 2525 and send email to an invalid email address...Exchange should bounce it, not allow it)

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-TransportAgent
Identity                                           Enabled         Priority
--------                                           -------         --------
Transport Rule Agent                               True            1
Malware Agent                                      False           2
Text Messaging Routing Agent                       True            3
Text Messaging Delivery Agent                      True            4


[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-AcceptedDomain | Format-List Name,AddressBookEnabled


Name               : sscorp.com
AddressBookEnabled : True
```

Some sites have said to make sure the receive connector is not set to "externally secured"
I have double checked this setting and it's not set that way.

I've seen this site [Exchange 2013 recipient filtering - reject after RCPT TO](https://serverfault.com/questions/493261/exchange-2013-recipient-filtering-reject-after-rcpt-to) and I am using port 2525 like it suggests

Has anyone else come across this before?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you need to have the Edge Transport role installed; without that this will not work